# R cannot open an existing file

Tags: r

Can somebody explain to me possible reasons and solutions to why R cannot open a connection to an existing file?

```
> file.exists("config.R")
[1] TRUE
> source('config.R')
Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) : 
  cannot open the connection
```

Answer (score 1):

From the **R Documentation**:

> `file.exists` returns a logical vector indicating whether the files named by its argument exist. (Here ‘exists’ is in the sense of the
>   system's stat call: a file will be reported as existing only if you
>   have the permissions needed by stat. Existence can also be checked by
>   `file.access`, which might use different permissions and so obtain a
>   different result. Note that the existence of a file does not imply
>   that it is readable: for that use `file.access`.)